# OpenCL and GPU with Android OpenCV SDK

Tags: android, opencv, opencl, gpu

I have found that from the following links, The OpenCL and GPU is available in OpenCV.

http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.5/modules/ocl/doc/ocl.html.

http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.5/modules/gpu/doc/gpu.html

Is it possible to obtain OpenCV Android SDK with OpenCL and GPU.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25087440/android-opencl-image-processing-example-on-samsung for an example of running openCL on a Samsung device.

Answer (score 0):

For mobiles you can use NEON accelerated extensions (ARM). If you have NVIDIA Tegra device, you can check [NVIDIA Tegra Zone](https://developer.nvidia.com/category/zone/mobile-development). This [link](http://www.pgroup.com/lit/articles/insider/v4n2a3.htm) may help but, its not for OpenCV.

Answer (score 0):

For update's sake:
OpenCL is somewhat supported in OpenCV:
http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki/ChangeLog#249

Don't know the details yet myself, researching as well

Answer (score 0):

Yes, opencv4android packages openCL into ocl module already. In android project, you should include "opencv2/ocl/ocl.hpp", then you can use cv::ocl::func_xxx(), which is openCL function actually.

Comment: It appears OpenCL support is being intentionally removed in some Android devices. Also do the Android device needs to be rooted for OpenCL support ?